How do I remove intersecting faces inside an object to make it suitable for 3D printing?
I am working on a project that involves 3d reconstruction of 2d bladder ultrasounds.
In order to validate the accuracy of the model at computing the volume of the bladder from this 3d US, I am using simple geometries like a sphere. I basically created a point cloud on a sphere of a radius, r, for 12 z -planes (e.g points are on x-y plane for certain z plane indexing.
When I run this code through the reconstruction code, I am left with an .obj file that looks like the below photo when imported to Blender.
Does anyone know how I can just keep the exterior of the shape, and remove intersecting faces?
Basically, the aim is to see how the volume of the sphere changes with an increased number of vertices on each plane.

